# AWS lambda function not processing POST variables

Tags: json, node.js, lambda, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function which works correctly when I test in the AWS Lambda dashboard, however any json data I post to the function appears to be ignored.

If I test with curl:

> curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
>   "email":"email@.email.com", "fullname":"Mr Tester", "address":"1
>   Street" }' https://API.Gateway.url

In the lambda function code using

> exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {..}

event.email is always null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a entry in your apigateway configuration, under resources, select post method -> integration request , under body mapping templates. you can add a application/json content type and add a template for matching your request body json.

The template can be generic like given below or can be designed to suit your parameters.

```
  {
    "body" : $input.json('$')
  }
```

Refer this for further information : [Cannot send POST data to Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45981625/cannot-send-post-data-to-lambda)