# Cannot send POST data to Lambda

Tags: node.js, post, aws-lambda

I am trying to send data to my lambda function however the function is not getting my data, the `event` variable is empty. I am not getting any errors and when I test the function in my API Gateway it works fine. So I am not sure what is happening. My code for sending data to Lambda is below.

```
var options = { 
    method: 'POST', 
    url: 'correct api url', 
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: s
}
```

for `data: s` within my console looks like this `data: '{"article_url":"a url here"}'`

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Are you using pass-through or a specific API Gateway mapping template? If you have a mapping template, please include it in your question.

Comment: @MarkB no template so I would assume it's a pass through

Comment: Are you sending the entire event object to the log and verifying that it is totally empty?

Comment: @MarkB correct the entire event is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "Integration Request" configuration, make sure you've checked the "Use Lambda Proxy integration" checkbox.

And make sure your output matches the schema defined here to avoid errors:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format

```
{
    "isBase64Encoded": true|false,
    "statusCode": httpStatusCode,
    "headers": { "headerName": "headerValue", ... },
    "body": "..."
}
```

Comment: When I do that I get the error `Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response`

Comment: Here is my callback from the lambda function `callback(null, {"statusCode": 200, "body": JSON.stringify(response.sentences)});` is it that the headers are missing as to why it is saying the JSON is malformed?

Comment: That is likely the issue. You're going to need the header indicating that your payload is application/json

Comment: ok changed this to a test and it is still getting the error `Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response` my test response is `callback(null, {"statusCode": 200, headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, "body": {'testing':'test'}});`

Comment: Body is not a valid JSON string. Try stringifying that `{testing}` object.

Comment: Same error with this code `callback(null, {"statusCode": 200, headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, "new": JSON.stringify({'testing':'test'})});`

Comment: "new" is not a valid response property. I believe you meant "body"?

Comment: Ok got it thanks for your help new callback is `callback(null, {"statusCode": 200, "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, "body": JSON.stringify({"body": "results"})});`

Comment: If this solved your issue, please accept the answer. Thanks.